# port issue for Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana, elk

When using default 9200/5601 for ES and Kibana, both ES and Kibana are up.

I'd like to change ports as below. ES is up at http://localhost:34343/ But Kibana doesn't work. I tried both service name ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:34343 and container name ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://my_elasticsearch:34343

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: my_elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 34343:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.3

    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:34343
    ports:
      - 5666:5601
```

I got the error for Kibana

```
"tags":["error","elasticsearch-service"],"pid":8,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.3:34343"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

I believe you may have made a mistake in you `docker-compose` file.
You are providing Kibana with the port that is mapped on the host `34343` and not the host the service is listening to `9200` in the docker internal network.

Having a read at the [networking documentation of docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) helped me out

## To fix

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.16.3
    container_name: my_elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 34343:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.16.3

    environment:
      # - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch: 34343
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - 5666:5601
```